# Which address does a pointer to a struct point to in C?

Tags: c, struct

I ran the sample code on TutorialsPoint under the title of "C-Structure" and did some experiment. I tried to print the address of the pointer to a struct and addresses of some components in the struct, 
here is the struct:

```
typedef struct Books {
   char title[50];
   char author[50];
   char subject[100];
   unsigned long long  book_id;
} Book;
```

and here's what I've typed:

```
printf( "%p\n", ptr); // print the address of pointer
printf("%p\n", book.title);
printf("%p\n", book.author);
```

in which *ptr is pointer to the struct:

```
Book var = {"Stalin", "Jean-Jacques Marie", "dictatorship", 9788020612113};
Book* ptr;
ptr = &var;
```

then this is the output address of ptr:

```
0x7fff298eb8b0
```

this is the address of book.title:

```
0x7fff298eb980
```

this is the address of book.author:

```
0x7fff298eb9b2
```

I find this a little confusing, because I've read on Wiki that struct

*"defines a physically grouped list of variables to be placed under one name in a block of memory, allowing the different variables to be accessed via a single pointer"*,

so I thought struct should behave like an array, but it doesn't seem to be so, since the pointer doesn't point to the address of the first component.

Could someone please explain a bit, what address does this pointer point to?

here is the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Books {
   char title[50];
   char author[50];
   char subject[100];
   unsigned long long  book_id;
} Book;

int main(){

    Book book;
    Book var = {"Stalin", "Jean-Jacques Marie", "dictatorship",    9788020612113};
    Book* ptr; // pointer to struct
    ptr = &var;

    printf( "Book title : %s\n", ptr -> title);
    printf( "%p\n", ptr); // print the address of pointer
    printf("%p\n", book.title);
    printf("%p\n", book.author);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I don't see any relationship between `book` and `ptr`. Do you mean `var`?

Comment: @Kevin yes, I think it should be the address of var, and I 've forgotten an important line here, I've just added it

Comment: You've shown us disconnected code fragments. Please show us a complete self-contained program that we can run for ourselves. [mcve]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cee3ca2930a1155

Comment: What I mean is, you have 3 variables here: `book`, `var`, and `ptr`. `ptr` points to `var`, so why do expect any relationship between `ptr` and the address of `book`?

Comment: And you haven't shown us the definition of `book`. Did you define two different objects of type `Book`, named `book` and `var`? This is why we need a [mcve].

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just messed up your test code. `&var` and `var.title` are the same location in my tests.

Comment: The numbers given show the difference between book.title and ptr to be 208 bytes, exactly the size of your struct, so I suspect you declared the variable book right after the variable var.

Comment: Sorry, now I have already attached the whole code.

Comment: We note that `0x7fff298eb980` and `0x7fff298eb8b0` differ by 208 bytes, which seems to be the size of your structure. Since `book` and `var` are two separate variables, and `ptr` points to `var`, not `book`, the output is not unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer to a struct contains the memory address (beginning) of the struct.  The address of fields in the struct will be the memory address of the struct + an offset which is the size of all preceding fields (plus alignment padding).  For example, ideally in this structure

```
struct s
{
  char c1;
  uint16 u16;
  uint32 u32;
}

struct S s;

if the &s is 100 then
&s.c1 would be: 100 + 0 = 100
&s.u16 would be: 100 + 1 = 101
&s.u32 would be: 100 + 1 + 2 = 103
```

Unfortunately, it is not quite that ideal/simple because most processors require 16-bit values to be located on a 16-bit address boundary (multiple of 2), 32-bit values to be located on a 32-bit address boundary (multiple of 4), etc.

Using your Book structure:

```
typedef struct Books
{
   char title[50];
   char author[50];
   char subject[100];
   unsigned long long  book_id;
} Book;

Book book;

if the &book is 100 then
&book.title would be: 100 + 0 = 100
&book.author would be: 100 + 50 = 150
&book.subject would be: 100 + 50 + 50 = 200
(and assuming long long is 8 bytes)
&book.book_id would be: 100 + 50 + 50 + 100 = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of `ptr` must be the same as address of first byte of `var.title`. And from this test it seems exactly as expected (first two lines `0xffdb19d4`):

http://codepad.org/ktcMv9jL

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> so I thought struct should behave like an array, but it doesn't seem to be so, since the pointer doesn't point to the address of the first component.

Since `book` and `var` are two distinct variables, they will have different addresses. Your code has initialized `ptr` with the address of `var`. Your print statements compare the address in `ptr` with addresses of member objects in the variable `book`.

If you change your code to compare `ptr` with the addresses of member objects in the variable `var`, you would see that `ptr` does in fact have the same address as the first component of `var`.

```
ptr = &var;
printf( "%p\n", ptr);      // print the address of pointer
printf("%p\n", var.title); // address of first component of var
```